# Installed Spark, built against right hadoop version , getting cannot assigned requested address error

Tags: apache-spark

When I try to run the Spark shell, this is what I get

```
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /10.9.247.151:0
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:298)
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteServer.start(Server.scala:53)
    at akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport.start(NettyRemoteSupport.scala:89)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:94)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:588)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:595)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:111)
    at spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:51)
    at spark.SparkEnv$.createFromSystemProperties(SparkEnv.scala:67)
    at spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:79)
    at spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:841)
    at <init>(<console>:10)
    at <init>(<console>:22)
    at <init>(<console>:24)
    at .<init>(<console>:28)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $export(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:629)
    at spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request$$anonfun$10.apply(SparkIMain.scala:890)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.bind(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:138)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleServerSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:90)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:64)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.bind(Channels.java:569)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:187)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap$Binder.channelOpen(ServerBootstrap.java:343)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelOpen(Channels.java:170)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.<init>(NioServerSocketChannel.java:80)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:158)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:86)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:277)
    ... 27 more
```

FYI, the IP address that it says it can't bind to is the IP of the master machine on hadoop (not the same as the machine that I am running this on). I am using the right versions of both Hadoop and Scala, and am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

Spark tries to resolve your hostname and then bind to resolved IP address. In your setup this IP address is unavailable (wrong DNS/Network Card setup).
Try to edit your `/etc/hosts` (or `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` record and add a line: `<your ip address> <your hostname>`

Comment: It still binds to 10.9.247.151?

Comment: yup, not sure why.  @nekto0n

Comment: What does    host $(hostname)    claims to be your IP?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the local ip-address spark binds to by setting the environmental variable  SPARK_LOCAL_IP='some ip-address'. I had a similar problem.

Comment: Worked for me setting local IP to the IP of the host. Did not try setting it to 127.0.0.1